# After opening jquery UI dialog the background of jquery Ui cant be click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have jquery Ui dialog after i open it and press the [x] i cant click the button behind it. It's like the modal didn't disappear. After refreshing the page i can click the button again.

This is my jquery code:

```
function ShowPopup() {
        $(function () {
            var dlg = jQuery("#dialog").dialog(
                {
                    modal: true,
                    title: "Select date!",
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 340,
                    height: 295,
                    show:
                        {
                            effect: "blind",
                            duration: 300
                        },
                    hide:
                        {
                            effect: "blind",
                            duration: 300
                        }

                });
            dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
        });
    }
```

asp code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" OnClick="btnShow_Click" Text="Show" Width="150px"/>


<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">
    <table>
         <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="200px" Text="Select Date "></asp:TextBox>
         </td>
         <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" Width="200px" Text="Select Date "></asp:TextBox>
         </td>
    </table>
  </div>
```

CS code:

```
 protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtName.Text = "Ricky";
    txtLocation.Text = "Golf Hills";

    if (txtLocation.text != "South woods")
    {
       string script = "alert(\"Location is not South woods\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                 "ServerControlScript", script, true);
    }
    else
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "ShowPopup", "ShowPopup();", true);

    }
```

Comment: Why $(function () {} is needed in this ShowPopup() function?

Comment: @NikunjSoni sorry but i don't no I just saw this and copied it and it worked i'm just new to jquery.